# s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'schema' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have a more or less simple task to build a XSD schema of but I'm not sure if my idea here is right. Especially for the element `comment`.

Customers can make **purchase orders**. A purchase order includes at least one **order position** (product name, quantity, and price are obligatory; comment and shipping date are
optional).

A purchase order has a **date** (order date) and an optional **comment**.
Customers can specify different **addresses** (billing and
shipping). Only the shipping address is required.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xs:element name="purchase-order">
        <xs:element name="order-position" type="order-position-type" minOccurs="1">
            <xs:complexType name="order-position-type">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="product-name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:integer"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="comment" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="shipping-date" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="order-date" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="billing-address" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="shipping-address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

So does the same element, here `comment`, appear multiple times? Now I have min and maxOccurs for `comment` but in the sequence so it's probably wrong.

Where else are errors you maybe see? Or can I make it even easier? The point `at least one order position` let me create an element before the complexType to tell that the minOccurs value is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok to have `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` on an element in a sequence.

Here are some of the issues that you do have to address, however:

1. `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` should be `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`.  (**Fixes title message error**, but there will be more to fix after that...)
2. `<xs:element name="purchase-order">` cannot have an `xs:element` child.  Use a `xs:complexType` child and `xs:sequence` grandchild.
3. Declaration of the `order-position` element cannot have both a `type` attribute and a `xs:complexType` child.  Use one or the other.

Others remain (meeting your cardinality requirements, for example), but here is an XSD that has the above syntax issues fixed, at least, to help get you unstuck:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="purchase-order">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="order-position" type="order-position-type" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="order-date" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="billing-address" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="shipping-address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="order-position-type">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="product-name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
      <xs:element name="comment" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2"/>
      <xs:element name="shipping-date" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

You'll want to use an XML editor or validating parser to check that your XSD is [well-formed and valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

Comment: Ah okay. Very helpful! So I see I was not soooo wrong but there were essential errors like this two following elements. And also the thing to put it as complexType after the element. Thank you!

Comment: Ah sorry one question. Like in the task you have a comment for the `order-position` and one for the `purchase-order` itself. Can this still be written like in your answer? Seems wrong for me @kjhughes

Comment: Yes, you can have a `comment` element both as a child of `purchase-order` (todo) and as of child of `order-position` (done).  Consider declaring `comment` globally and using `xs:element/@ref` for each occasion of its use.